# Function inside a ts file

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get a function to log a string to the console on a click of the button. I'm writing the function inside a typescript file while using Angular. I keep getting an error saying that the function hasn't been defined but I don't know where I'm going wrong

```
ngOnInit() {
  function myFunction(){
      console.log('button has been clicked');
}
```

```
resume:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

Comment: Can you please share your html/template with us.

Answer (score 5):

ok, try this:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.myFunction();
} 
myFunction(){
  console.log('button has been clicked');
}
```

ngOnInit() is the method that is called when creating your component by angular but it does not seem that you can create methods inside.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Angular don't find the button click function in the required scope.
you should separate your functions like this. And then bind you button's click event to the function.

In your Typescript file

```
ngOnInit(){

}

myFunction(){
  console.log('button has been clicked');
}
```

In your html template file

```
<button (click)="myFunction()">Button</button>
```